# How do I know if my js/CSS files is too huge?

Tags: javascript, css, file, browser

What is the optimal filesize of a JavaScript and CSS files of a websites?

Comment: As small as possible is probably optimal! Look into minification if you haven't.

Comment: If the word 'huge' comes to mind, start cutting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Zero bytes.  It sounds facetious, but there's no such thing as an "optimal" file size.  The bigger it is, the longer it will take your page to render.  How fast is the connection to your web site for your visitors?  If it's a video-oriented site, for example, it's probably relatively fast since people with 64 kbps modems aren't going to be trying to stream anything that large.  If it's a simple text site displaying information to satellite users in Zimbabwe, it might be quite slow.

So let's imagine that the average speed is 1.5 Mbps.  Realistically, halve that to 750 Kbps.  That's about 94 KBps.  So if your CSS file is 50 KB and your javascript file is 50 KB, it will take a little over one second to download them for your visitor.  Is your site highly interactive, with users expected to click around quickly from one thing to another?  If so, then that once second delay could be extremely irritating.  If not, then it might be perfectly reasonable.

If you find your file size getting too large, you might want to consider looking at some "minifying" utilities; these are utilities that will take your code, replace variable names ("my_descriptive_variable") with shorter names ("a"), remove whitespace and comments, etc.  Sometimes these utilities can reduce your code to 10% of what it was before.

Ultimately, though, "optimal" is completely subjective.  Try designing minimal script/CSS files, add a bunch of KB of comments to them, and load your page on low-end connections until you consider it too slow.  That will give you a pretty good idea of what your upper limit should be.

Comment: Optimal size is 0 only if you're only optmizing for CSS file size and your example doesn't seem correct.  If the file is cached it will take no time, and if a CSS file if 50KB, it will be much less than 50Kb acrsso the wire (which is what counts) and even if it were large and took "a long time" to download, that doesn't necessarily mean user interaction wlil be delayed that amount.  Minifying CSS is good, but usually does relatively little compared to other optimizatoins

Answer (score 16):

The smaller your external files the better.

But perhaps more important than having a smaller size is having [fewer separate resources](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http), meaning fewer HTTP requests.  For example, a single 1MB file often loads faster than ten 100KB files.  You're better off when you combine multiple CSS (or JavaScript, image, etc.) files into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you really want to take advantage of, though, is cacheing. So put all your shared utilities and styles into one file, minify that, and include it on every page. Most modern browsers will download it only once, and download it quickly (being minified). Then, minify the page-specific ones also and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The total size of a page while it is being viewed by the user should be approx ~100kb. This makes it easier for the user view and Search Engines to crawl your website.

The concept of "page size" is defined as the sum of the file sizes for all the elements that make up a page, including the defining HTML file as well as all embedded objects (e.g., image files with GIF and JPG pictures). It is possible to get away with page designs that have larger page sizes as long as the HTML file is small and is coded to reduce the browser's rendering time.

Comment: @Coding-Freak - isn't the page size very dependent upon the content being shown? Or is this an over-arching size constraint that I just haven't read about yet?

Comment: Referencing one's sources is considered polite.  See http://www.useit.com/alertbox/sizelimits.html for the original advice this answer offers.

Comment: I read this value somewhere on a Google Webmaster's forum discussion. It is for sure dependent on the content being served. But if this value is wrong, then could you please correct me? I would love to know the appropriate one @Brett/

Comment: @Coding-Freak - had never seen any values, so I appreciate you pointing them out! thanks.

Comment: I am sorry my SO peers that i forgot to reference the article where i got the information source. I wont forget it again.

Comment: @Rob Raisch Thanks for the source. I found a link within useful too: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/response-times.html

Answer (score 0):

Typically your Javascript file should be less than 25kb and your CSS file should be less than 10kb, the smaller the better, these numbers will vary depending on resource and items. Sometimes this is not possible but you can minimize whitespace (spaces, returns and removing comments). Ideally each line should be one style definition in your CSS and your Javascript should be beautified (redundant code removed and code that is used over and over to be put in functions) and minimized to be on one line if possible.

Typically your CSS should be loaded in the head of the page and the JS right before the closing body tag. This is so the page can still load while waiting for the CSS or JS to load. Most browsers and servers will only load about 4 resources from one server at a time. If possible you can seperate your resources over multiple servers/subdomains to create asynchronous loading.

The asynchronous loading applies to all aspects of a webpage; images, CSS, JS, and html. All my knowledge has been collected and learned from working on sites for over 10 years.

Comment: I dont know what kind of a site I can run with a 25kb of javascript file used. Now-a-days, css3 based sites and basic themes in most cms itself takes 100s Kbs to have a decent site.

Comment: @blackops_programmer This answer is over 2 years old and at the time that was what the ideal size that was reported. That does not necessary apply today. But there are still ways to get your files smaller. Now a lot of talk is about minimizing the number of calls to the server. Either way both can be accomplished to a degree by removing white-space, combining files, or compressing. Even now my sites unoptimized are running at around 300kb for both css and js. On page load a script runs them through minimizing (removing comments and white-space) and compressing the files. Final sizes vary.

Comment: Fair enough and thank you for your updated post on an old topic. I was looking around to find out what size does webmaster stretch upto now-a-days. Right now, considering a lot of developers are using css fw like boostrap, js lib like jqeury, mootools, etc.. its just making the page a bit bloated too due to all the extra lib that needs to be downloaded and its very hard to get it down to less than even 100kb. Like you said, minifying css, jss and reducing the http request does seem to do a slightly better job than unoptimized files. Thanks again for your reply. Cheers! :)