# Does length of CSS code determine the loading speed of website?

Tags: html, css, performance, frontend

I am beginner. I want to know, Does length of CSS code determine the loading speed of website??
Please tell me about relation of code and loading speed of website.

Comment: Only if it's very long, if so there's more data to load, hence it will take longer. Things like minifying and removing unused styles can speed it up. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55866495/979052

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a duplicate of at least these answers:

- [Does too much CSS affect performance of a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244568/does-too-much-css-affect-performance-of-a-web-site).
- [How do I know if my js/CSS files is too huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195660/how-do-i-know-if-my-js-css-files-is-too-huge)

In short, it depends on how much of a length you are talking about. If your css is in the 100s, 1000s of kb or more, loading speed would definitely be affected. If not, then not, at least not for internet speeds of 3G or more.